# Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi from this context

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help. I'm trying to make a backup of my worksheet that makes it take the data from the worksheet and put it in another worksheet but it's giving this error!

[image]

Comment: Try enclosing the upper script into a function declaration.  Your building your entire function in global space which will have it run everytime to call any function so I'm guessing you would not want that.  I sure wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

`SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` can't be used in stand alone projects ejectuted from the script editor, it only works when the stand alone project is used as a Google Editor Add-On.

I know that your script is an stand alone project because the screenshot shows the share button.

In order to be able to use `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` you should,

1. test it as Editor Add-on
2. use it as Editor Add-on
3. use it from a script contained in a spreadsheet

Related

- ["SpreadsheetApp.getUi() cannot be called from this context"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36117119/1595451)
- [Google Script Cannot call FormApp.getUi() from this context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41052256/1595451)
- [Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 2, file "Code")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65270842/1595451)

Comment: I can solve the problem of SpreadsheetApp.getUi() but now I have the following problem Exception: Range not found

Comment: @Z87 Post a new question including the code and the textual error as text (see [mcve]) and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].